# How to modify Chrome ExtensionInstallWhitelist?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to install extensions on Chrome but it seems to "decide" for me what I should and should not install, which is very frustrating. I have navigated to the "`chrome://policy/`" and the `ExtensionInstallBlacklist` is set to "`*`", how can I change this or add my extensions ID's to the `ExtensionInstallWhitelist` array? I cannot find this file anywhere on my machine (MAC) and I have looked everywhere including as I found in other threads as a `/Library/Managed Preferences/username/`. How can I modify the policy settings?

Comment: How do you install your extension?

Comment: I just click add from the chrome extensions and it tells me that the extension has been blocked by the administrator

Answer (score 2):

Then I would suggest *contacting your administrator*. This setting is put into your machine by a workgroup policy.

Even if you were able to change the value locally, it's in place for a reason, and you may get in trouble for that.

Note that you would need a local administrator to access the file. [According to the docs](http://www.chromium.org/administrators/mac-quick-start), it should indeed be in `/Library/Managed Preferences/<username>`. And modifying it will not help in the long term.

Comment: I don't have an administrator to contact, I have full access to install anything on my machine except this so I need to change the preferences. I will not get in trouble to change it, I just don't want to mess up the computer settings. Again, I am unable to find this Library/Managed Preferences file, any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I resolve mine:

1. Find the extension that you want to install and try to install it
   0.5 Copy the extension from the pop-up
2. Navigate to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome\ExtensionInstallWhiteList
3. Add a new REG_SZ with the next sequence number and paste the data
4. Restart Chrome and try to install the extension again

Answer (score 1):

**Only for MacOS**
Google Chrome restricts installing 3rd-party extensions for better security. The official method to bypass such limitation is to add custom [policy](https://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3). In current version (60) of Chrome, there is a policy entry for whitelisting extension called [ExtensionInstallWhitelist](https://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#ExtensionInstallWhitelist). On macOS, one can easily add such policy by running the following command in Terminal:

`defaults write com.google.Chrome ExtensionInstallWhitelist -array id`

Replace id with your actual extension ID correspondingly. The ID can be found in `chrome://extensions` by clicking the “Developer mode” box. If you want to add multiple IDs, put `id1 id2 id3`, etc. after `-array`. Restart Chrome to take effect. To check if the policy works, visit `chrome://policy`. To remove the policy, simply run:

`defaults delete com.google.Chrome ExtensionInstallWhitelist`

This could help install open-source Chrome extensions such as BaiduExporter without warning.

[Original source](https://linusyang.com/2017/09/14/chrome-extension/)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove it:

> Win+R

> regedit

> Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome

> Select the folder containing ExtensionInstallWhiteList

> Right click delete

Comment: Can you explain how this helps with the question?

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: @MauriceSchleußinger it will allow installing extensions